# Исключение "Access violation at address ..."

Tags: delphi

Что обозначает эта ошибка?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Access Violation` - это косяки с доступом к памяти. Попытка чтения/записи туда, куда вы писать не можете (в вашем случае вы читаете память по адрему $FFFFFFE4).

Как правило, это значит что вы не проинициализировали объект должным образом перед работой с ним, либо уже успели его освободить и вызываете его метод, либо гдето заползли в чужую память (например при работе с динамическими массивами) и испортили таким образом объект.

Поможет запуск в режиме отладки, выявление места, где бросается исключение, анализ кода на предмет спровоцировавших исключение манипуляций с памятью.

Comment: Я работал только с файлом. Попробую перепроверить свой код.

Comment: Ну покажите как вы работали. То что вы знаете, что работали только с файлом сужает нам область поиска проблемы.

Comment: > Поможет запуск в режиме отладки

Скриншотик-то уже от отладчика. Если в первом случае текст обозначает ровно то, что написано, то здесь можно гадать хоть до 21 декабря. Ставлю 100 очков на то, что интерфейс релизнулся.

Comment: Ошибка происходит в этом месте программы:

      FileCheck.Create(GetCurrentDir + '\run.fch', fmCreate);
      FileCheck.Read(state, 4);
     if state='show' then begin
                MainForm.Show;
                FileCheck.Seek(0, soFromBeginning);
                FileCheck.Write('', 4)
              end;
     FileCheck.Free;

Comment: `FileCheck`, я так полагаю, имеет тип `TFileStream`? Тогда предположения верны, и вы работаете с несозданным объектом.

`FileCheck.Create(GetCurrentDir + 'run.fch', fmCreate);` - конструктор никогда не вызывается на самом объекте (объект-то еще не создан). 

Исправьте на `FileCheck := TFileStream.Create(GetCurrentDir + 'run.fch', fmCreate);` и все  получится.

Answer (score 1):

> доступ нарушения по адресу 00403AA3 в
> модуле screen.exe. Чтение адреса
> FFFFFF4;

Очевидно с памятью что-то намудрил. Код лучше выложи, где срабатывает ошибка.

Comment: > доступ нарушения
Может "нарушение доступа"?